# How to decrypt this crashlog?

Tags: ios, iphone-4

**How to decrypt this!?**

*I can't reproduce it! I need your help, please.*

```
Incident Identifier: 7C65F52C-E872-4513-89BE-EC869FB3F41A
CrashReporter Key:   634a6bc6b8aa653f0e377d8d83304ed15a845a57
Hardware Model:      iPod2,1
Process:         Rocket Master [564]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/79A9AE3A-9C77-42A8-BC6A-13DCBD961CDC/Rocket Master.app/Rocket Master
Identifier:      Rocket Master
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-10-01 21:17:27.823 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00089320 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008930e kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00089302 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000a004e abort + 54
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00065a00 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 588
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00008e44 _objc_terminate + 160
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00063100 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00063178 std::terminate() + 16
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x000632a0 __cxa_throw + 100
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000742c objc_exception_throw + 104
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000a425c +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 64
11  Foundation                      0x00052ef0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 56
12  Rocket Master                   0x0006cc24 0x1000 + 441380
13  Rocket Master                   0x000042f4 0x1000 + 13044
14  Rocket Master                   0x0006bad0 0x1000 + 436944
15  Rocket Master                   0x00003abc 0x1000 + 10940
16  Rocket Master                   0x000034c0 0x1000 + 9408
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0004d09c __invoking___ + 60
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0004cf76 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 110
19  Rocket Master                   0x000661e0 0x1000 + 414176
20  Rocket Master                   0x00063388 0x1000 + 402312
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000493dc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 20
22  Rocket Master                   0x000c656c 0x1000 + 808300
23  Rocket Master                   0x000c7190 0x1000 + 811408
24  Rocket Master                   0x000c9198 0x1000 + 819608
25  UIKit                           0x0008483c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 580
26  UIKit                           0x00083e70 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 388
27  UIKit                           0x0007d5f0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 444
28  UIKit                           0x0007ccf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6804
29  GraphicsServices                0x00005dd8 PurpleEventCallback + 1024
30  CoreFoundation                  0x00035e40 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00035dfe __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158
32  CoreFoundation                  0x0002809e __CFRunLoopRun + 574
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00027d74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00027c82 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
35  GraphicsServices                0x00004e84 GSEventRunModal + 188
36  UIKit                           0x00004f8c -[UIApplication _run] + 564
37  UIKit                           0x000024cc UIApplicationMain + 964
38  Rocket Master                   0x00002310 0x1000 + 4880
39  Rocket Master                   0x0000227c 0x1000 + 4732

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0003534c kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00103768 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x001031b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00103354 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008bc38 _pthread_wqthread + 392
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b64 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008cb00 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008be14 _pthread_wqthread + 868
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b64 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000e70 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003354 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000287e8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00027ff0 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027d74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c82 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   WebCore                         0x00002ee8 RunWebThread(void*) + 552
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b67c _pthread_start + 364
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d00c thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000e70 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003354 mach_msg + 60
2   AudioToolbox                    0x00123b3c AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 96
3   AudioToolbox                    0x00001bac CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 220
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b67c _pthread_start + 364
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d00c thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000e70 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003354 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000287e8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00027ff0 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027d74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c82 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   AudioToolbox                    0x00002050 GenericRunLoopThread::RunLoop() + 48
7   AudioToolbox                    0x000211e0 TRunLoop<AQClient>::Entry(void*) + 160
8   AudioToolbox                    0x00001bac CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 220
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b67c _pthread_start + 364
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d00c thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e0fb2b4
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x0025f23c      r6: 0x2fffde2c      r7: 0x2fffde3c
    r8: 0x000d982e    r9: 0x00000888     r10: 0x3ebbd520     r11: 0x00258dd0
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffde3c      lr: 0x30d2a315      pc: 0x30d2a320
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0xe6fff +Rocket Master armv6  <8e1075a9434ecf8f8d9d278f8fda20de> /var/mobile/Applications/79A9AE3A-9C77-42A8-BC6A-13DCBD961CDC/Rocket Master.app/Rocket Master
  0x1f0000 -   0x1f1fff  dns.so armv6  <d94bf29d2f94f4cac8fb25d075252bc2> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe28fff  dyld armv6  <b51ec2c56beac6899646c51fe28b6fae> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30071000 - 0x300cffff  CoreAudio armv6  <a61686be17503bae6deec28a9715759d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x300d2000 - 0x300dbfff  AccountSettings armv6  <783d903e23362c53a80c69f7cebdfc3c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x300dc000 - 0x3011dfff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <73161041047b78a921c0fdd2c7e75455> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x30123000 - 0x3012bfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <cb5520300c93870fc03fbefcc748543b> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30209000 - 0x30216fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <47e45645d22904edeecdf0839b4bb967> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3035d000 - 0x303acfff  Security armv6  <f00ee08adc8f84dadac891097161c1d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30497000 - 0x304dcfff  CoreText armv6  <d01fb0c73a7fab4af8f495ec30844690> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x304dd000 - 0x304dffff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <7705fbf8b67a464330dacf53e37292b4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x304eb000 - 0x304ebfff  Accelerate armv6  <6dcd8231db5a848bb71f3afb46760d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x304ec000 - 0x304f1fff  CaptiveNetwork armv6  <035433a5acc9804d189e391e7d9a27a2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x304f9000 - 0x30500fff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <2e235630c504b859eeffa6ef6be993c6> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30693000 - 0x306d6fff  AddressBook armv6  <af71434a2a8c766346983face1008df1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x306f7000 - 0x306f7fff  vecLib armv6  <c278d2882e2e84e6003850561f0f20cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x309b1000 - 0x30a96fff  QuartzCore armv6  <c41b8dd3520d0265692e822d98820ec0> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30c7e000 - 0x30c80fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <93930f3d8cbada04abc2c0fe648d2e95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30c81000 - 0x30ca0fff  EAP8021X armv6  <7dbd1063e8b949fb78a965eaca4b82ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30ca1000 - 0x30ddbfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <7646d5cdfe189fb2b9d8b95477e5a8db> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30e09000 - 0x30e0cfff  ApplePushService armv6  <ab15352e7e86960ffb39cbe0de19e21c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x30e0d000 - 0x30e1bfff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <712df47cb008c407ea7b3615d078cfc6> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30e1e000 - 0x30e61fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <de066fd08dfb3db322f6899bb8e6e18b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30f84000 - 0x30f90fff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <82e1f0e232b1035b8ad6b0db3e1ff3a3> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x30f91000 - 0x3276afff  UIKit armv6  <5c33da0496d64d9a205f108083d7e334> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x327f6000 - 0x327f7fff  DataMigration armv6  <844a55ab4c6aad4d0914cb1fc23272cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x328f6000 - 0x329cbfff  WebKit armv6  <43eb231b498f09855bcbd7dd5c4bc23d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x329cc000 - 0x32a10fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <a427d907a0d210b5fb8a42f58522d6ff> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32b85000 - 0x32b8afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <023d1dfdc41a2605e8b07cac981b60f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32bbf000 - 0x32bddfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <806782dbc2e4e7992c26bf32b4df0674> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32c0a000 - 0x32c10fff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <ad72f470c0efe965014d00ca412ea539> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32c17000 - 0x32c37fff  RawCamera armv6  <038b2a95d5ef7b9a48e07b39a6f86ca8> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x32c7d000 - 0x32ce3fff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <4b33c1269aa8fdf82789a5534f417625> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32ce4000 - 0x32ceffff  MobileWiFi armv6  <432fc2b6aecc422d0e849f0768d65acf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x32cf9000 - 0x32d5bfff  GMM armv6  <1b5a45b82d182e3f4c58d30a3369274e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x32d5c000 - 0x32d5dfff  CoreSurface armv6  <be966bacffe38f99ceb658613da6b74d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32d5e000 - 0x32d7dfff  Bom armv6  <cc5a0dd33692a3dbfa527757009c7426> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x32d7e000 - 0x32e67fff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <8b1828f3536baae8dc8d09f3e5e1d427> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x32f75000 - 0x32f78fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <a246b2a3f595b5721afa760716515a8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32f7b000 - 0x32f8afff  GraphicsServices armv6  <a98761a08ea64f9f3933850f7d1f2111> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x33018000 - 0x3306cfff  CoreMedia armv6  <b9f98e32b75ae5cd674a11c9e3e71757> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x330ac000 - 0x330bcfff  OpenGLES armv6  <546869be5a2591219a9bf65c65c9a362> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x330c0000 - 0x3326bfff  MediaToolbox armv6  <d3f7b9945d6cb465fd2bdd5fdeee2ce2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3326c000 - 0x3329dfff  AppSupport armv6  <93b6ed2f2bc2f62c9ae6de4601db3758> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x333b0000 - 0x33402fff  IOKit armv6  <93be31ff1bd1f7285a63069be2c69dae> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x334d2000 - 0x334e5fff  libmis.dylib armv6  <c3476ce3575c5ace6628274ab7ed499a> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x334e6000 - 0x33551fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <4b156cd9785534aa3b538d6f25bb8005> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x335d7000 - 0x33818fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <39e713c5715136d63261fb8396eb49be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x33819000 - 0x3381efff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <6644180b33a18614fa40829dc7004330> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3386c000 - 0x3398dfff  Foundation armv6  <5296264af1ac4f419189e0a48de6b128> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x339a4000 - 0x33b4efff  AudioToolbox armv6  <e4e6a9118b30645569ef935220f62bce> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x33c85000 - 0x3447efff  WebCore armv6  <a29f6709dfaa6d14a7c1a32fcdd953c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x34926000 - 0x3492cfff  MBX2D armv6  <ddf7c6ab6280ed98161004db01c3552b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x3492d000 - 0x34938fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <174b636d5ff2a55403e7656a32620635> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3493d000 - 0x34941fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv6  <c03d9bce5190081851cd75642dbc8f53> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x34970000 - 0x34a80fff  CFNetwork armv6  <6d3776508b8197ec3915c232ea3720d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x34abd000 - 0x34acffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <67fab4275abd0fe5880ba40d8954edc2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34ad4000 - 0x34b72fff  ProofReader armv6  <661556733279c1142615f07077521a3c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34bd5000 - 0x34c13fff  MBXGLEngine armv6  <ce6b44a92d5ada7e81ce5b44b9638a8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/MBXGLEngine.bundle/MBXGLEngine
0x34e2f000 - 0x34f25fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <fe03fd73746bb5d1a66283f88af99085> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x35099000 - 0x35160fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <84b34606127873ab6d53204175d715f0> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x35169000 - 0x352abfff  AudioCodecs armv6  <dabdc6cf03bff1af83387247c5f62d2f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
0x35426000 - 0x354b6fff  AVFoundation armv6  <d0f62f0c7283f92842dd8f16284e7956> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x354fe000 - 0x35503fff  IOSurface armv6  <e9f83ae3052b92d27dc877abf1614fdf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3554b000 - 0x3558dfff  VideoToolbox armv6  <a9b2b59c9a4c943236550a44a3bd1fe8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x3558e000 - 0x355f1fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <cebd79ec30314d11a8fcbe4b164d15c6> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3577b000 - 0x357b5fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <af4523ed2d29115fb78c479a90a9bc47> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x35845000 - 0x35848fff  MobileInstallation armv6  <70e1fb27c03d27edd9943932955eb72e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35849000 - 0x359a6fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <180059243236e419ac14ddc1571d315e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x35a17000 - 0x35a37fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <dcbb9247a801f3f9582de89d4c7d1811> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x35a38000 - 0x35e05fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6  <e6322ea5d57053f9d023f0870a89a82b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x35e5b000 - 0x35f19fff  ImageIO armv6  <e0005074c755aed7776b1b2f54069736> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x35f1a000 - 0x3609afff  CoreGraphics armv6  <6f082cb5b15e78807a93469e7fe59a25> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x360cb000 - 0x36193fff  Celestial armv6  <82acd6d300532afd21545e75cdf0e5ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x36264000 - 0x3637efff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <13279dd229bd9a3480d53e5404db2ac0> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3637f000 - 0x36391fff  PersistentConnection armv6  <471a2fdadc16456acc254a468058cbe3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x363c3000 - 0x36407fff  CoreLocation armv6  <eb546fd5a67066e5a805460ef3693272> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x36408000 - 0x36415fff  CoreVideo armv6  <31b0c94297302d84c9e6f69e91fdddb2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x36471000 - 0x364cdfff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <39d57220d98c7a9024d88c9591f5af59> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x365f5000 - 0x36613fff  OpenAL armv6  <033631f781f45e88a6940d7c86e8303f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
0x36717000 - 0x36723fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <8c7b34f9a4f00e4c76f5a14b59c506ec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3672c000 - 0x36794fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <b4b600385953ecfbfb931b5715402c38> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x367e1000 - 0x368b9fff  CoreFoundation armv6  <0bf817bd806e9d0c6654d0234576e58f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
```

Comment: It needs to be symbolicated in Organizer. The address location where it says Rocket Master will give you a hint to what caused the crash once the file is symbolicated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the comment I left here is a link to Apple's documentation [Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html). If you do not have the DYSM file used to build that version of your application then you will find it really difficult to solve without reproducing in the debugger.

Comment: Ok, I coudn't symbolice it, but I got following crash in an older log. (posted above)